# RAID drive not detected by Lubuntu installer

Tags: 12.04, system-installation, lubuntu, hard-drive, raid

I wanted to install LUbuntu on a old computer:
a P4C 2.53GHz asus P4PE 2go RAM with a WD raptor 36go (sata) as system disk and a maxtor damondmaxplus8 40Go (uata).

Currently Mageia 4 is installed into the raptor which I want to replace with Lubuntu 14.04.1.
I do not want erase the data in the maxtor.

This motherboard uses an Intel ich4 which does not supports sata, but it have an additional controller onboard (promise fastrack 376) for sata/pata raid.

When booting from install CD, choosing "Try Lubuntu first", everything is ok, drives are detected correctly: If I go on GParted or into the Disks utility or into the system profiler, disks and controller are detected correctly:

```
IDE interface       : Intel Corporation 82801DB (ICH4) IDE Controller (rev 02) (prog-if 8a [Master SecP PriP])

RAID bus controller     : Promise Technology, Inc. PDC20376 (FastTrak 376) (rev 02)
```

SCSI Disks:

> ATA Maxtor 6E040L0
>
> TSSTcorp CD/DVDW SH-S182M
>
> ATA WDC WD360GD-00FN

The Maxtor is shown as `sda` and the Raptor as `sdb`.

But when I launch "Install Lubuntu 14.04.1 LTS" the intaller says me that it did not detected any OS, and if I choose "do something else" the installer does not show me the raptor (`sdb`), only the maxtor drive is showed.

Is there a way to install Lubuntu on a drive connected to the promise SATA RAID controller or to force the install on sdb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've been able to get around this issue by myself but it will not works for everybody.

I disabled the single drive raid into the bios' controller.
as a result, few seconds are lost on the boot while the fasttrack controller scan for drives and the motherboard bios' cannot allow to boot on it.
But it also allow the installer to detect the drive and start the installation.

At the first reboot, I rebuilt the single raid drive, allowing to boot on it. As it's a single drive, nothing is modified on it by the fasttrack controller and so no data is lost.

But this method would not have work if I had a dual drive raid 0 or even maybe raid 1.